# Possible to only use certain characters of a line to authenticate with remote database?

Tags: android, database, authentication, encryption, remote-server

I'm looking to set up a remote database for user data for an Android application I am developing, but I don't want to use a server to handle the queries.   Instead, I am looking to see if there is a way to make either the database recieve or the app only send parts of a generated code for each user.

This is my thought process on how it would work:

```
User opens app for first time ->

app generates and stores on device specific code for user and visible to user-> 

example of User Code: MG0CG094CF08352FBZS3042C0890432 ->

when user inputs data on app -> 

data stored on device and sent to database when connection available ->

database receives only M0045328 for user identification for data input
```

The idea would be registration with the database without having to handle emails, passwords, etc., just the 8 digit user identification code.  The purpose of the 32 character app generated code would be for security and the user in the event they they get a new device or delete the app.

The security measure I'm thinking of instead of a server is for the database to only handle certain characters of the user code or for the app to only send certain characters.

```
User sees this in app: MG0CG094CF08352FBZS3042C0890432

Application only sends: Mx0xx0x4xxxxx5xxxxx3xx2xxx8xxxxx

Database reads:  M0045328
```

Obviously I don't want it to read like that in the source, so I need some discrete way for the app to exclude characters when sending information.  Problem is that I can't think of some way that it's possible to code it like that.  I essentially want the app to encrypt itself and only decrypt when it's sending information.  I obviously also don't want each code to decrypt the same way, so maybe the 32 character code could also include which characters to send?

Anyone have some idea about how to do this or would simply a server solution be easier?  Keep in mind I would prefer for it to handle it this way more than to use a server.

Answer (score 0):

For all your pseudo code, in the end you are trying to achieve a DRM structure. DRM is not feasible for devices that you have no control over. So you can only obfuscate things a bit. Trying to hide code is not likely to work; it's better to try and hide some kind of data to make that more difficult to find.

Comment: This would essentially remove the ability for a user to recover their information though.   I suppose the only real practical solution would be the server solution then?

Comment: That's certainly the only thing that directly comes to my mind.